# Working on AXL scripts for CUCM - why does this code handle only the last item?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cisco-axl

I am trying this code and its working fine:

```
phone_list = resp['return'].phone
for phone in phone_list:
    x = (phone.name)
    print(x)

try:
    resp = service.removePhone(name = x)    
except Fault:
    show_history()
```

`print(x)` gives 3 values:  `SEP003C53B8F073`, `SEP001FBB3669EA`, `SEP003A33B8F041`

The problem is when I pass this to the `try` block (`removePhone`) below to delete these 3 phones: it only deletes the first one.

I don't have any idea on how to assign variables to separate output items. Please let me know ho can I achieve this.

This is a protocol of the execution:

```
>>> phone_list = resp['return'].phone
>>> for phone in phone_list:
...     x = (phone.name)
...     print(x)
...
SEP001B53B8F075
SEP001FCA3669EA
>>>
>>>
>>> try:
...     resp = service.removePhone(name = x)
... except Fault:
...     show_history()
... else:
...     print('Deleted Phone:')
...     print( resp )
...
Deleted Phone:
{
    'return': '{C979366C-491D-4F12-B058-ECB789AA326A}',
    'sequence': None
}
```

This code just deleted the second phone (`SEP001FCA3669EA`) from the server. The first phone is still there.

Comment: Can you update the question with outputs of both tries? e.g.
Code: 
"<Code here>"
Current Output: X

Expected Output: Y

Comment: Perhaps you should indent the `try` ... `except` block so that it is executed for each loop iteration.

Comment: @Raghavsalotra: Please check the code now.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: i think its already indented. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your code is written, the `for` loop does not include the `try` block with the call to `removePhone`. As you can see, the `try` block is only entered after the loop is done.

After the execution of the loop, the value of `x` will be the last value from the loop. Consequently only the last phone is removed.

I think that you want to execute the `try` block for each iteration of the loop. For that, you have to indent it so that it becomes part of the loop:

```
for phone in phone_list:
    x = (phone.name)
    print(x)

    try:
        resp = service.removePhone(name = x)    
    except Fault:
        show_history()
```